# Execution time difference between heatmap and heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap, execution-time

I was trying to visualize quite big matrices (i.e. `10000 x 100`). Which seems doable if I assume that I am not interested in any additional clustering performed on columns or rows (which might be problematic since the dimension is high).

I started with the enhanced `heatmap.2` from the `gplots` package. Since I want to ignore clustering or reordering, according to the documentation and Stack suggestions (e.g. [heatmap.2 specify row order OR prevent reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959044/heatmap-2-specify-row-order-or-prevent-reorder)), I set proper parameters

```
heatmap.2(some_data, Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none", trace="none")
```

However, it turned out that the execution time was very long, as if it was **quadratic** depending on number of rows, which really is the case. See the dependency in the plot below.

On the other hand, when I have used the basic `heatmap` function from `stats` and suppressed the dendrogram

```
heatmap(same_data, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

calculation the execution time is **linear** and absolutely negligible.
Here is the comparison of the execution time.[image]

The code I used to generate the data for the above plots is

```
num.rows <- c(100, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000)

times.heatmap.2 <- sapply(num.rows, function(rown){
  m <- matrix(rnorm(rown*50), rown, 50)
  system.time(tmp <- gplots::heatmap.2(m, Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none", trace="none"))
})    

times.heatmap <- sapply(num.rows, function(rown){
  m <- matrix(rnorm(rown*50), rown, 50)
  system.time(tmp <- heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA))
})
```

Finally, the question.

- Does anyone have an idea why the `heatmap.2` has so long execution time and presumably quadratic dependence on the data size, even though it should ignore any quadratic operations (e.g. clustering)?
- Are there any parameters I should use or we should just dive into the source code of the function to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
install.packages("heatmap3")

num.rows <- c(100, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000)

times.heatmap.3 <- sapply(num.rows, function(rown){
  m <- matrix(rnorm(rown*50), rown, 50)
  system.time(tmp <- heatmap3(m, Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none", trace="none"))
})
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the question goes further: *Why heatmap.2 performs quadratic number of operations, when it clearly shouldn't?* It seems that the answer is not: `heatmap.2 is deprecated` use `heatmap3`, or is it?